# Staring using Spring to build a java application

Tags: java, spring

I would build a Java application and in the same time learn Spring framework. This application is not too complicated. It simply receives datas from the users and save them into databases for a future retrieving from the users. Now I would use Spring but I don't know if it is a good idea. What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 3):

Well for this small application no one will recommend you to use Spring as that means cutting a lemon with sword, but learning a new platform/framework is always a good idea,  since you want to learn Spring so its always better to learn something with some example or application development so i will suggest you to go ahead with your quest.

Spring in-itself is a vast sea and you firstly need to decided which all parts you want to learn, as a starting point i will recommend you to go ahead learn Dependency Injection principle of Spring and later you can start exploring other aspects of Spring.